# Is there a way to show button on basis of space left in a box made

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a custom box made from div. In that, I populate data from an array of strings in the form of the unordered list. This box of fixed size, so the problem arises if whole data does not fix the box.

```
Box
---------------- 
| * First      |
| * Second     |
| * Third      |
----------------
```

More than three elements are not fitting the box.
For that, I show more button which will redirect to more elements.

```
Box
---------------- 
| * First      |
| * Second     |
| More >       |
----------------
```

Here I want to show more button based on space left. Because might be 
this case

```
Box
---------------- 
| * First point|
| is long      |
| More >       |
----------------
```

What the best approach to take?

Comment: Do you want the last item to be shortened and ellipsis dots at the end ? or if an item can't fit in box you want it to be removed completely ?

Comment: let me explain my question more. imagine you have four items. only two items can't fit completely. the third item can fit but only half of it.

in this case you want to show two items and the "More" button ? or two items and a part of third item and the "More" button ?

Comment: use js to calc height of list

Comment: @masoud when the third item can fit but only half of it. in this case I want to show two items only and a more button. Clicking on `more` button will open pop-up with all list items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to add all the items in array to the DOM and then calculate the height of box. if box size doesn't have enough space for button and for items you need to remove items one by one.

here is my approach :

```js
let buttonHight = $('button').outerHeight();
  let boxInnerHeight = $('.box').height() - parseInt($('.box').css('padding-top')) - parseInt($('.box').css('padding-bottom'));
  let listHeight = $('.list').outerHeight();
  
 
 
 while(boxInnerHeight - buttonHight < listHeight){
 
 $('p').last().remove();
 
 buttonHight = $('button').outerHeight();
 boxInnerHeight = $('.box').height() - parseInt($('.box').css('padding-top')) - parseInt($('.box').css('padding-bottom'));
 listHeight = $('.list').outerHeight();
 
 $('button').css('display','block');
 
  
 }
 $('p').each(function(item){
  $(this).css('opacity','1');
 })
```

```css
.box{
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #bbbbcc;
  padding:10px;
  position: relative;
}

.list p{
 opacity: 0;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.list button{
 display:none;
  height: 25px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="list">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vulputate sem non vehicula euismod. Vestibulum feugiat vel nisi et iaculis. Phasellus ut varius sem.</p>
    
    <button>see more</button>
  </div>
</div>
```